# Range.Find works on individual cell, but skips it when put in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the full code. It takes a key word or phrase from the bottom of the sheet, finds it in the top of the sheet, and pastes a neighboring cell next to the key word. So, if the bottom says "Population," it finds population at the top, goes one cell over to get 35,987, and pastes 35,987 next to Population at the bottom of the sheet. (In reality, it's pasting a formula, but the copy/paste is not the issue).

```
Sub FindTest()
'
' FindTest Macro
'
Dim cArray As Variant
Dim rArray As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
cArray = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
rArray = Array(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 42, 44, 46, 48, 54, 56, 58, 60, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79)
For Each i In cArray
    For Each j In rArray
'Start one cell up and one cell to the left of BI ILF
        Range("Q141").Offset(j, i).Select
        fname = Selection.Text
'Range for floc is entire original Attributes section
        Set floc = Range("P5:Y130").Find(fname, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not floc Is Nothing Then
            faddy = floc.Address
            Range(faddy).Offset(0, 1).Select
            Selection.Cut
'Range matches original starting cell
            Range("Q141").Offset(j, i + 1).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
            GoTo Skip
        End If
Skip:
    Next j
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This works in general, but there are several key words it just doesn't find even though they match completely. To test the find function, I created the code below to target a particular key word that the original code didn't find. This time, it did find it exactly as intended.

```
Sub Searcher()
'
' FindTest Macro
'
        Range("AF153").Select
        fname = Selection.Text
'Range for floc is entire original Attributes section
        Set floc = Range("P5:Y130").Find(fname, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not floc Is Nothing Then
            faddy = floc.Address
            Range(faddy).Offset(0, 1).Select
            Selection.Cut
'Range matches original starting cell
            Range("AG153").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If
End Sub
```

So: Why did it work when I hard code a particular cell but skip over it when it does the same function but within a loop? The key words range that don't work range from single words, to short alphanumeric phrases. As a reminder, the original code does find about 60% of the key words.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this ?

```
for i = 1 to 11 step 2
    for j = 2 to 79 step 2
        ''Your code
    next j
next i
```

I don't think you need an array if the difference between two variables is same.

But if you want to define an array, then do it like this:

```
dim rArray(1 to 6) as integer
rArray(1) = 1
rArray(2) = 3
rArray(3) = 5 
rArray(4) = 7
rArray(5) = 9
rArray(6) = 11
''Do same for cArray
    for i = 1 to 6
        '' Your code
        range("Q141").offset(rArray(j),cArray(i))
    next i

etc.
```

Comment: So, this wasn't quite the answer, but it prompted me to reconsider whether the loop constraints were correct. I took the array out and just did a regular loop (by one) and it performed much better. Thanks!

Comment: You are a shining star. Welcome to StackOverflow !